# Como funciona o setup.py do python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como funciona o *setup.py* do python e qual o intuito em usá-lo?

Usar o docker evita o uso do setup.py?

Answer (score -1):

O setup.py trabalha na construção e instalação de módulos do python, dentro da API distutils, a partir da versão 3.12 ela será descontinuada e removida.

[Setup.py](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/install/index.html#:%7E:text=A%20execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20de%20setup.py,fazer%20uma%20coisa%20por%20vez.)

Atualmente um dos instaladores mais  utilizados é o pip

[Pip](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/installing/index.html#installing-index)

Aconselho que faça a leitura da documentação nos links passados acima, lá possui muita coisa bacana que podem sanar suas dúvidas.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).